# creating virtual directory programmatically iis7

Tags: windows, iis-7, virtual-directory

I got a website, would like to create a number of subsites under this one. Subsite will be created through a GUI, so virtual directory should be created on the fly. I have been searching for code to do that one. 
thanks !